# Sum of two 'rare' matrices, read as coordinate X, coordinate Y and a value

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, matrix, struct

As I was going through problems with `structs` on pbinfo.ro, I found a problem in which I'm given the dimensions of two matrices, the number of `nonzero` elements for each matrix (N1, respectively N2) and then N1 + N2 groups of 3 numbers as follows:

- The coordinates, X and Y
- The value located at those coordinates

What I have to do is write a program that does the sum of these two matrices (they both have the same dimensions) and outputs the sum as given in the input (X, Y, and the value at the coordinates).

Here is the full text of the problem:

### [Matrice-Rara | www.pbinfo.ro](https://www.pbinfo.ro/?pagina=probleme&id=1323)

> ### Requirement
>
> Two rare matrices are given and you 
>   are asked to calculate their sum.
>
> A matrix `A (n, m)` is called rare if most of its elements are equal to
>   zero (at least half). Because of the small number of nonzero numbers, a
>   rare matrix `A (n, m)` with `k` nonzero elements can be stored using an 
>   array `X` containing `k` triplets of form (line, column, value) corresponding to 
>   the nonzero values of the matrix. Elements of the array `X` are stored in 
>   lexicographical order by `line` and `column`.
>
> For example, the matrix with `n = m = 3`:
>
> ```
> 1 0 2
> 0 0 5
> 0 2 0
> ```
>
> will be saved in `X` this way: `{(1,1,1), (1,3,2), (2,3,5), (3,2,2)}`.
>
> ### Input data
>
> The input file `matrice_rara.in` contains on the first line the 
>   dimensions of the two matrices
>   `n m`, representing the number of lines 
>   and columns, and `N1 N2`, the number of nonzero elements of matrix `A` and 
>   matrix `B`. Then the following `N1` lines will contain triplets for the 
>   matrix `A` in lexicographical order, and the last `N2` lines will contain 
>   triplets representing the nonzero elements of matrix `B`, also in 
>   lexicographical order.
>
> ### Output data
>
> The output file `matrice_rara.out` will contain on the first line the 
>   number of nonzero elements in the matrix `C` and then the matrix 
>   itself in the form of triplets in lexicographical order, one per line.
>
> ### Restrictions and clarifications
>
> - `1 ≤ n, m ≤ 1,000,000`
> - `1 ≤ N1, N2 ≤ 300,000`
> - `-1,000,000,000 ≤ A[i][j], B[i][j] ≤ 1,000,000,000`
> - `Time Limit: 1 second`
> - `Memory Limit: 64 MB / 8 MB`

What I tried is I read all the triplets in one array of triplets, sorted the array and then added the values of the elements that have the same coordinates into the first element in the array that has the repeating coordinates.

Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

ifstream cin("matrice_rara.in");
ofstream cout("matrice_rara.out");

struct matrix
{
    int coord1, coord2;
    long long val;
} data[600001];

bool operator<(matrix const &a, matrix const &b)
{
    if (a.coord1 == b.coord1) {
        if (a.coord2 == b.coord2) {
            return a.val < b.val;
        }
        return a.coord2 < b.coord2;
    }
    return a.coord1 < b.coord1;
}

int main()
{
    int lin, col, unNul1, unNul2;
    cin >> lin >> col >> unNul1 >> unNul2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= unNul1 + unNul2; i++)
        cin >> data[i].coord1 >> data[i].coord2 >> data[i].val;

    sort(data + 1, data + unNul1 + unNul2 + 1);

    int unNull = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= unNul1 + unNul2; i++)
    {
        int start = i;
        while (data[i + 1].coord1 == data[i].coord1 && data[i + 1].coord2 == data[i].coord2 && i + 1 <= unNul1 + unNul2)
            i++, data[start].val += data[i].val;
        if (data[start].val)
            unNull++;
    }
    cout << unNull << "\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= unNul1 + unNul2; i++)
    {
        if (data[i].val)
            cout << data[i].coord1 << " " << data[i].coord2 << " " << data[i].val << "\n";
        while (data[i + 1].coord1 == data[i].coord1 && data[i + 1].coord2 == data[i].coord2 && i + 1 <= unNul1 + unNul2)
            i++;
    }
}
```

The code above gets 65 points out of 100, getting correct answers for 6 of the 9 tests, and Wrong Answer for the rest (no TLE).

Any help?

Comment: Please don't use online judge or competition sites as a basic learning resource, they won't really teach you anything useful other than being good at such sites and not much else. Instead I suggest you [get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read. If you switched to better learning resources you wouldn't (hopefully) have such bad habits as using one-based array indexes (among other things).

Comment: As a possible hint about what your problem *might* be: You have an off-by-one error, where you *will* go out of bounds of the initialized data in the `data` array. And if you had learned C++ properly then you probably would not have that error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did read some books, but they only initialized me in programming. Also, those are the ones that taught me this one-based index programming. And since then (5 years ago), I've been programming this way. I try my best to get rid of this habit, however, it isn't easy, as it feels like something instinctive by now. Online Judges aren't my learning resource, don't worry. I only use them for exercising my capabilities of writing correct, clean code.

Also, 600001 is enough to ensure the elements fit, otherwise the Online Judge would give me `Caught Fatal Signal 11`.

Comment: In that case I apologize, but still implore you to get one of the *good* books listed in the (curated) list I linked to. And it should also hopefully explain why putting ` && i + 1 <= unNul1 + unNul2` will not save you from going out of bounds (hint: the logical operators does [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the advice, I downloaded those books. When I'll get more money, I'll buy them too, they look like they're worth reading.

Also, just read that Wikipedia page and tested my evaluation (added another element in the array, identical to the last) and it did *not* go beyond the limits, while the evaluation goes like this:

    - Are the first coordinates the same? (`true`)

    - Are the second coords the same? (`true`)

    - Is `i <= unNul1 + unNul2 + 1`? (`false`)


If you still think it does, please give me some reasoning, as I don't understand why.

Comment: Did you check the amount of memory you are using ? The Judge fixed a limit

Comment: @Damien I'm sorry to be rude, but did *you*? It's way under the 64 MB limit for the global variables and way under the 8 MB for the locals.

Comment: I just calculated that your array has a size of 9.6MB. Use of `sort` increases the memory effectively used. And in your question it was not clear what 64MB/8MB effectively refer to. I did not check the on line text. Sorry to have bothered you

Comment: BTW, those are [sparse matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just managed to get to 100 points. Basically, my mistake was the way I defined the `operator<`, or in the source I posted here (since then I rewrote it a couple of times), **the fact that I wrote an `if` statement wrong, not the `while` one**. Here's the new source:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream cin("matrice_rara.in");
ofstream cout("matrice_rara.out");

struct matrixEntry {
    int l, c;
    int val;
} matrix1[300001], matrix2[300001], finalMatrix[300001];

bool operator< (const matrixEntry &a, const matrixEntry &b)
{
    return a.l < b.l || (a.l == b.l && a.c < b.c);
}

bool operator> (const matrixEntry &a, const matrixEntry &b)
{
    return a.l > b.l || (a.l == b.l && a.c > b.c);
}

int matrixSum(int matrix1Size, int matrix2Size)
{
    int i = 1, j = 1, k = 0;
    while (i <= matrix1Size && j <= matrix2Size)
    {
        if (matrix1[i] < matrix2[j])
            finalMatrix[++k] = matrix1[i++];
        else if (matrix1[i] > matrix2[j])
            finalMatrix[++k] = matrix2[j++];
        else
        {
            finalMatrix[++k] = matrix1[i++];
            finalMatrix[k].val += matrix2[j++].val;
            if (finalMatrix[k].val == 0)
                k--;
        }
    }
    while (i <= matrix1Size)
        finalMatrix[++k] = matrix1[i++];
    while (j <= matrix2Size)
        finalMatrix[++k] = matrix2[j++];
    return k;
}

int main()
{
    int unNul1, unNul2, lin, col;

    cin >> lin >> col >> unNul1 >> unNul2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= unNul1; i++)
        cin >> matrix1[i].l >> matrix1[i].c >> matrix1[i].val;
    for (int i = 1; i <= unNul2; i++)
        cin >> matrix2[i].l >> matrix2[i].c >> matrix2[i].val;

    int unNull = matrixSum(unNul1, unNul2);
    cout << unNull << "\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= unNull; i++)
    {
        cout << finalMatrix[i].l << " " << finalMatrix[i].c << " " << finalMatrix[i].val << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to see the official tests too. Note that this program allocates a maximum of 300001 entries for the final matrix, which may be not enough, given the constraints. Also, try implementing only `operator<`, and use `... else if (matrix2[j] < matrix1[i]) ...`. There shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: @Bob__ Yeah, true, could have done that… 4 lines that have no point whatsoever. But anyway, the 300001 limit is fine, since it's indexed from `1`, meaning it'll need one more entry than an array indexed from `0`.

Comment: No, that's "Ok", I'm referring to the 1 ≤ N1, N2 ≤ 300,000 constraint. *Both* N1 and N2 could be as big as the maximum and the resulting number of non zeroes *could* be up to N1 + N2. Anyways, if this passes all the tests, it never happens.

Comment: @Bob__ You want to know why that ***never*** happens? Because you cannot do the sum of two matrices of different sizes. And, if you do the sum of two matrices of the same size, the resulting one can't be double the size. :)

Comment: Actually, disregard that, the tests should have been over that 300001 limit, as that's not the size of the matrix, but the number of triplets given.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the logical AND operator `&&`, and the left-hand side expression is `false` then the right-hand side expression is not evaluated. This is called [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

It also means that the left-hand side *must* be evaluated first, before the code know if the right-hand side needs to be evaluated or not.

Now lets take a conditional expression from your code, and simplify it a little:

```
data[i + 1].coord1 == data[i].coord1 && i + 1 <= unNul1 + unNul2
```

This is two sub-conditions combined with the `&&` operator:

1. The left-hand side `data[i + 1].coord1 == data[i].coord1`, and
2. The right-hand side `i + 1 <= unNul1 + unNul2`

Due to the short-circuit nature of the `&&` operator, the left-hand side (`data[i + 1].coord1 == data[i].coord1`) must be evaluated first before the right-hand side (`i + 1 <= unNul1 + unNul2`).

Now if `i` happens to be equal to `unNul1 + unNul2`, then the left-hand side expression will use an index that is out of bounds by one.

To not go out of bounds, you need to check the index `i` *first*, which is easiest done by switching the order of the condition to

```
i + 1 <= unNul1 + unNul2 && data[i + 1].coord1 == data[i].coord1
```

Now `i + 1` will not be out of bounds.

---

As for why it's important it's because uninitialized data will have *indeterminate* values, and using them in almost all ways will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And with the loop condition as you currently have it, then you *will* use an index into the parts of the array `data` that is uninitialized.

Comment: Just submitted the solution with `i + 1 <= unNul1 + unNul2` first. Same result, same tests fail. Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the intent of the posted code, the OP tried to imlement this algorithm to sum two sparse matrices:

- read the non zero elements of *both* matrices into a single array big enough to store the maximum number of elements admissible by the problem constraints. Note that the input is well formed and the triplets representing the n.z. elements of the two matrices are already lexicographically sorted (row-major) for each one of those.
- Sort the whole array, lexicographically. Note that in the compare function the *value* of the n.z. element is considered too.
- Traverse the array and sum the values of two consecutive elements if they have the same coordinates and store the result in the first one. If the resulting value is non zero, the count of n.z. is updated accordingly. The out of bounds accesses, here, were already pointed out.
- Traverse the array a second time to print out the non zero values of the resulting matrix, skipping the values of the successive elements with the same coordinates. Same out of bounds accesses, as before.

Besides the UB due to the accesses out of bounds, it's unclear to me if the accepted solution requires to *actually* check if the resulting value of each element is non zero.

Even if that is the case, I think that we can take advantage of the already sorted input and incrementally create the resulting matrix by "merging" the two sources. In the following snippet (testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y9uvnt3pDZjBfVrb)) I also simplified the comparisons between two elements, by using a single 64-bit value representing a position instead of two 32-bit coordinates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

constexpr uint64_t pos_from(uint32_t r, uint32_t c)
{
    return (static_cast<uint64_t>(r) << 32) ^ c;
}

constexpr uint32_t row_from(uint64_t pos)
{
    return (pos >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

constexpr uint32_t col_from(uint64_t pos)
{
    return pos & 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

template <typename T>
class SparseMatrix
{
    uint32_t rows_{}, cols_{};
    std::vector<std::pair<uint64_t, T>> nzs_;
public:
    SparseMatrix(uint32_t r, uint32_t c, uint32_t nzs = 0)
        : rows_{r}, cols_{c}
    {
        nzs_.reserve(nzs);
    }

    std::istream& read_non_zeroes_from(std::istream& is, uint32_t n)
    {
        while(n--)
        {
            uint32_t r, c;
            T value;
            if ( (is >> r >> c >> value)  &&  value)            
                nzs_.emplace_back(pos_from(r, c), value);
        }
        return is;
    }

    std::ostream& write_non_zeroes_to(std::ostream& os)
    {
        os << nzs_.size() << '\n';
        for (auto const& i : nzs_)
            os << row_from(i.first) << ' ' << col_from(i.first) << ' ' << i.second << '\n';
        return os;
    }

    friend SparseMatrix operator+ (SparseMatrix const& a, SparseMatrix const& b)
    {
        assert(a.rows_ == b.rows_  &&  a.cols_ == b.cols_);
        SparseMatrix sum(a.rows_, a.cols_, std::max(a.nzs_.size(), b.nzs_.size()));

        auto i = a.nzs_.cbegin();
        auto j = b.nzs_.cbegin();
        auto dest = std::back_inserter(sum.nzs_);
        while ( i != a.nzs_.cend()  &&  j != b.nzs_.cend() )
        {
            if ( i->first < j->first )
            {
                *dest = *i;
                ++i;
            }
            else if ( j->first < i->first )
            {
                *dest = *j;
                ++j;
            }
            else
            {
                auto sum_value = i->second + j->second;
                if (sum_value)
                    *dest = {i->first, sum_value};
                ++i;
                ++j;   
            }
        }
        std::copy(i, a.nzs_.cend(), dest);
        std::copy(j, b.nzs_.cend(), dest);
        return sum;
    }
};

int main()
{
    uint32_t n, m, N1, N2;
    if ( !(std::cin >> n >> m >> N1 >> N2) )
        std::cerr << "Error: unable to read initial data.\n";

    SparseMatrix<int32_t> a(n, m, N1);
    if ( !a.read_non_zeroes_from(std::cin, N1) )
        std::cerr << "Error: unable to read triplets of the first matrix\n";

    SparseMatrix<int32_t> b(n, m, N2);
    if ( !b.read_non_zeroes_from(std::cin, N2) )
        std::cerr << "Error: unable to read triplets of the second matrix.\n";

    auto c = a + b;
    c.write_non_zeroes_to(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: Well, since I didn't really understand much of your code, I decided to see how the Online Judge would react to it. Guess what? Apparently, this also gets 65 points. Also, yes, if the resulting value of two elements is zero, that final element has to be omitted from the output.

In such conditions, I'd love to see the official tests, but we cannot.